# How to send multiple arguments to jQuery click function?

Tags: jquery, click, parameter-passing

Currently I'm using something like:

```
$('.myclass').click(function(){  
    var msg = $(this).attr('id');  
    alert(msg)
});
```

And HTML:

```
< a href="#" class="myclass" id="101">Link</a>
```

If I need additional parameters how would I read them? Also is the current way I am using the proper way? Originally I was using hidden input fields so it was already a step up. :p

Comment: It's considered bad convention to start an id with a number, but if you're not using it as an id, then it's probably ok - last time I checked, Firefox won't recognize an id that starts with a number.

Comment: yes, that is correct fudgey... don't start your ids w/a number, but the idea in my answer is still the same.

Answer (score 19):

[jQuery Events](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/bind#typedatafn)

[jQuery .click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

```
$('.myclass').bind("click", { Param1: "", Param2: 2 }, function(event){
    alert(event.data.Param2);
});
```

Comment: Would that mean I'd have to include this function on the same page? Currently all my js stuff is in a separate file.

Comment: So, I in the event data it is possible to pass an entire json object, isn't it? Nice feature.

Comment: @Roger you can have the function outside too, just make sure to parse the arguments in your external function using the event.data.ParamX method as the reply shows. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`bind()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/bind#typedatafn) and send additional data to the event handler as [`event.data`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.data)

Answer (score 1):

this may not be the best method, but something i have done is to hyphen delineate the id attribute with other params, like `id="101-red-420582"` which all three mean different things and can be easily broken down using the `split()` function. not the best, per se, but i've done it and it works.

Comment: Coincidentally I came up with this exact idea and it was working fine, but like you said not too sure if its the correct way and sometimes the string might get quite large (not sure if there is a limit of the id).

Comment: I use a similar method all the time, but instead of the 'id' I use the 'rel' attribute. I believe either will hold as much information as you need, including HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Quick Solution

`<p class="msg_head" id="837" rel="a" **till_limit="9"**>Header-1 </p>`

and you can refer as

```
 $(this).attr('till_limit');
```

This is similar solution like define your own ID and refer the element as per your requirement.

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) in your posts.