# How to send multiple parameters to jQuery click function?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-forms-plugin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to send multiple arguments to jQuery click function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541127/how-to-send-multiple-arguments-to-jquery-click-function)

I want to pass multiple arguments to a Jquery function. Below is the Javascript sample code. I want to convert this javascript function to a jquery function. How can I pass that arguments into a jquery onclick event?

```
<a onclick="showState('state_name','state_id')">ADD STATE </a>

function showState(state_name,state_id){
openbox_state(state_name,state_id);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps I'd use datasets here:

HTML:

```
<a data-state_name="state_name" data-state_id="state_id" >ADD STATE</a>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
...
  $('a[data-state_id]').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    showState($this.data('state_name'), $this.data('state_id'));
    return false;
  });
...
});
```

You actually don't have to jwrap the clicked object, as you can get the attribute values with either [**dataset**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.dataset) API (if you have the luxury of not supporting IE9-, though) or simple `getAttribute` method. Yet I found this syntax more clean and readable.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way is:

```
<a href="#" id="myanchor" data-nm="state_name" data-id="state_id">ADD STATE </a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $('#myanchor').on('click', function() {
      openbox_state( $(this).data('nm') , $(this).data('id'));
   });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Jquery Code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 var state_name=$('#txtName').val();
 var state_id=$('#txtid').val();
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('a').click(function(){
        showState(state_name,state_id);
         });
});



function showState(state_name,state_id){
   openbox_state(state_name,state_id);
  }

</script>
```

Your HTML:

```
<a href="javaScript:void(0);">ADD STATE </a>
<input type="text" id="txtName" value="Tom Cruse" />
<input type="text" id="txtid" value="1" />
```

this jquery take the values from inputs, by using their id and use them as parameters to call the method.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is horribly heavy. Why use inputs ?

Comment: @dstroy: Because question is not exactly clear , i have just shown the way so that any body can understand what it mean, i was trying to show that how to get values from html for using in jquery.

Comment: It seems you're lacking some code to initialize txtName. Only IE initializes window properties for elements having an ID. And even on IE, this wouldn't give them a val function.

Comment: for your kind information, i m using them daily in my work routine and i do check my applications in all  browser.

Comment: [Check the console](http://jsfiddle.net/r9psd/)

Comment: Edit it so , i can cleary get you what you want to teach me !

Comment: You probably need something like `var txtName = $('#txtName');` at the start of your script.

Comment: yes you r right, i forgot to use selector here ,show that it can find input and then get values from it.

Comment: Now its  right? check and vote

Comment: @dystroy: sorry for misbehaving with you, thanks but it was a mistake ok

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is to pass additional data to be used in the event handler, jQuery click event binder supports this already. But in order to use it you have to bind the event handler through code instead of inline binding.

$(function(){
   $('#id').click({additional : "data"},function(){  // handler code});
});

Check documentation: http://api.jquery.com/click/